# how to add mp3 player to facebook members from my facebook application

Tags: facebook, profile, fbml, share

I am making an application that reads an mp3 file , and I want the user to be able to share the mp3 player on his profile and be shown like the image below:

[image]

and not like the normal share button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed id="mpl" height="16" name="mpl" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="176" 
       src="http://hexol.org/partners/player/player.swf" 
       flashvars="author=Bindas Radio&amp;description=Bindas Radio&amp;captions=Bindas&amp;duration=9999999999&amp;file=http://74.63.104.27:8234/;stream.mp3&amp;link=http://www.fnradio.net/sms.php&amp;backcolor=000000&amp;frontcolor=FFFFFF&amp;lightcolor=CCCCCC&amp;screencolor=000000&amp;volume=40&amp;autostart=true&amp;repeat=always" 
       wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" 
       allowfullscreen="true" quality="high"></embed>
```